# Using BarChart[ ] tooltips to illustrate where data is coming from

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, visualization

I am currently visualizing word and phrase frequency across a large database of textual information (approximately 108MB spread across 307 text files). My goal is to have a way to quickly see what files are the most relevant and in a visually attractive format (although this project will probably also demonstrate that just having textual representation is always clearer).

Right now I have the following:

```
SetDirectory["/MYMATHEMATICADIRECTORY/"];
filelist = FileNames[];
viewerCount1 = {0};
viewerCount2 = {0};
word1 = "freedom";
word2 = "liberty";
Do[
  searchDB = StringSplit[Import[filename]];
  AppendTo[viewerCount1, Count[searchDB, word1]];
  AppendTo[viewerCount2, Count[searchDB, word2]];
, {filename, filelist}]

list3 = Take[viewerCount1, {2, -1}]
list4 = Take[viewerCount2, {2, -1}]
```

The FileNames[ ] generates a list such as: {"001ABbenevolat.txt-cleaned.txt", "002abnature.txt-cleaned.txt", "003aboriginaldocs.txt-cleaned.txt", "004ABpresse.txt-cleaned.txt", "005acadian.txt-cleaned.txt", "006acadiedelile.txt-cleaned.txt","007acfa.txt-cleaned.txt"} [except with 307 entries, all numbered].

list3 generates a list such as: {0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 2, 0, 0, 0, 10, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 11, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 7, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13,...} and so on.

The command:

```
BarChart3D[{list3, list4}, BarSpacing -> {0.5, 0}, ChartLayout -> "Grid"]
```

Generates something close to what I want (imagining them as file folders sticking up). However, I want to add meaningful tool-tips. By default, it comes up with frequency. Would there be a quick way to also include the filename the frequency is attached to, as well as the frequency? i.e. a tool-tip that brings up '007acfa.txt-cleaned.txt -- 32' where 32 occurrences appear in file 7?

Comment: Is there a character missing in the second argument to `Sort` in the calculation of `sortedfrequency`?  Also, if you initialize `viewerCount#` with `{}`, you shouldn't need the `Take` to construct `list3` etc...

Comment: So the *i* th number in `list3` corresponds to the occurrences of the word in the *i* th file?

Comment: @BrettChampion The `sortedfrequency` was a redundant command - I've edited to remove it. Thanks for the `Take` advice, I knew there must have been a better way than mine.

Comment: @BrettChampion Yes, the _i_th number in `list3` corresponds to it being the _i_th file - i.e. the seventh number in list3 will be the file 007acfa.txt-cleaned.txt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an example, suppose you data is something like

```
list3 = RandomInteger[30, 30];
list4 = RandomInteger[30, 30];
filelist = Table["file " <> ToString[i], {i, 30}];
```

Then you could do something like

```
BarChart3D[{
  MapThread[Tooltip[#2, Row[{#, " -- ", #2}]] &, {filelist, list3}],
  MapThread[Tooltip[#2, Row[{#, " -- ", #2}]] &, {filelist, list4}]}, 
 BarSpacing -> {0.5, 0}, ChartLayout -> "Grid"]
```

**Edit**

Another way is to use `LabelingFunction`:

```
BarChart3D[{list3, list4}, 
 LabelingFunction -> 
  (Placed[Row[{filelist[[Last[#2]]], "  -- ", #1}], Tooltip] &), 
 ChartLayout -> "Grid", BarSpacing -> {0.5, 0}]
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
BarChart3D[{list3, list4}, 
   ChartLabels -> Placed[filelist, Tooltip],
   ChartLayout -> "Grid",
   BarSpacing -> {0.5, 0}]
```

**Edit**

Forgot you wanted the height in the tooltip also, for which you do want to use `LabelingFunction`.  Let's go ahead and include the word itself also:

```
BarChart3D[{list3, list4}, 
   ChartLabels -> {Placed[{word1, word2}, None], Placed[filelist, None]}, 
   ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
   BarSpacing -> {0.5, 0}, 
   LabelingFunction -> (Tooltip[Row[Flatten[{#3, #1}], " - "]] &)
   ]
```